# How to restore the state of a QPainter after drawing

Tags: c++, qt

To move those images on screen, using two translate function. But because of using two translate function the position value in first translate is adding to 2nd translate function. So how to clear the first translate function value. Below is code:

```
painter->translate(100,100);
painter->drawPixmap(uavIcon->m_paintPosition, *uavIcon->m_icon);

painter->translate(100,100);
painter->drawPixmap(targetIcon->m_paintPosition, *target->m_icon);
```

second image is placing at (200,200)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save and restore the state of your painter when you change the coordinates system using `QPainter::save()` and `QPainter::restore()` functions:

```
painter->save();
painter->translate(100,100);
painter->drawPixmap(uavIcon->m_paintPosition, *uavIcon->m_icon);
painter->restore();

painter->save();
painter->translate(100,100);
painter->drawPixmap(targetIcon->m_paintPosition, *target->m_icon);
painter->restore();
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answer. If you just want to reset the transforms that you applied you can also use the [’resetTransform’](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#resetTransform) function.